# A simple implication of an approximation theorem by Komlós, Major and Tusnády

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have been reading through the  [PhD thesis of Professor Aue](http://kups.ub.uni-koeln.de/1112/1/aue.pdf) on change point analysis based on invariance principles. There's a particular argument I have not been able to follow:

Let $(\varepsilon_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i]=0$, $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i^2]=\sigma^2$ and $\mathbb E[|\varepsilon_i^{\nu}|] < \infty$ for some $\nu > 2$. The author claims that this sequence of random variables fullfills the following weak invariance properties (Assumption 2.3.1. in the thesis):

1. $\big\vert  \sum_{i=1}^m \varepsilon_i \big\vert = \mathcal{O}_P(\sqrt{m})$ as $ m \to \infty$.
2. There is a sequence of Wiener Processes $\{W_m(t): t\geq 0 \}_{m \in \mathbb N}$ and a positive constant $\sigma >0$ such that:

$$
\sup_{\frac{1}{m} \leq t < \infty} \frac{1}{(mt)^{\frac{1}{\nu}}}\bigg\vert \sum_{i=m+1}^{m+mt} \varepsilon_i - \sigma W_m(mt)\bigg\vert = \mathcal{O}_P(1) \; ,\; m\to\infty
$$,

where $\nu > 2$.

In page 29 of the thesis, the author now claims that the above immediately follow by the seminal approximations of Komlós, Major and Tusnády (1975, 1976) and Major (1976a). For convenience I also state theorem 1.2.4. of the thesis, which is the result of Komlós, Major and Tusnády.

> Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb E[X_i]=0$, $\text{Var}(X_i)=1$ and $\mathbb E[|X_i^{\nu}|] < \infty$ for some $\nu > 2$. Then there exists a Wiener process $\{W(t):t \geq 0\}$ [assuming the probability space is rich enough, otherwise just define $\widetilde{X}_i$ in a richer probability space with the same distribution as $X_i$] such that $\sum_{t=1}^{\lfloor T \rfloor} X_t -W(T) = \mathcal{o}(T^{\frac{1}{\nu}})$ almost surely as $T \to \infty$.

Now if I see it correctly, property 1) even follows from the central limit theorem. OTOH, it really is not obvious to me how the 2nd invariance property follows. Of course there are some obvious connections (e.g. $\sigma$ of (2) is just the standard deviation of $\varepsilon_i$), but I am still not sure how one could go about proving it.

Answer (score 1):

any proof of this result is going to be technical to say the least. KMT is now a classical result in probability that was very surprising at its time. It provides the optimal rate of growth for the skorohod embedding theorem. For a "simple" proof that relies heavily on stein's method see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.0501v3.pdf Is the simplest proof I've seen, and it provides a brief history of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for a proof of KMT though, but of the weak invariance of the example sequence. According to the author of the thesis, this follows "trivially" from KMT, yet I do not see how. Maybe I should just contact the author.